# Onclick срабатывает на второй клик

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, как сделать, чтобы обработчик к кнопке срабатывал после первого клика, а не второго?
    Вот часть разметки

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("Conditioner/" + item.Key, "Applience"))
{
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="OnOff" id="conButton"> 
        <img src="~/Images/112132-200.png" />
    </button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="temperatureTB" id="temperatureTB" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Set" id="setButton" />
    <br />
    <span id ="spanState"></span>
}
```

JS файл

```
var counter = 1;
var intervalHandler;
var temp;

var element = document.getElementById('spanState');
var textBox = document.getElementById('temperatureTB');

var setBut=document.getElementById('setButton');
setBut.onclick = function () {
    var temp = textBox.value;
    function count() {
        element.innerText = counter;
        counter++;

    }
    var btn = document.getElementById('conButton');
    intervalHandler = setInterval(count, 1000);

    var handler = setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(intervalHandler);
        alert('Stop. Your temperature now is' + temp);


        btn.click();

    }, 8000);
}
```

Метод контроллера

```
    public ActionResult Conditioner(int id, string action, string temperatureTB)
    {
        IDictionary<int, Applience> applienceDictionary = (SortedDictionary<int, Applience>)Session["Apps"];
        Conditioner con = applienceDictionary[id] as Conditioner;
        switch (action)
        {
            case "OnOff":
                con.On_Off();
                break;
            case "Set":
                con.Temperature = Convert.ToInt32(temperatureTB);
                con.Air_Conditioning();
                break;


        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть предположение, что дело в `type="submit"` на кнопке.

Первым, что произойдет - это событие `submit`, а только потом ваш обработчик. Поэтому можно просто сделать кнопку "кнопкой" - `<input type="button" />` и повесить на нее обработчик.

Однако, если посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/6dhu2qxz/), тот я ничего не менял и все работает с первого раза. Получается что где-то еще идет обработка вашей кнопки `Set`.

Comment: обработка идет еще в контроллере там меняется значение con.Temperature = Convert.ToInt32(temperatureTB);Я поставила <input type="button" /> код работает с первого раза, а можно как-то сделать, чтобы вначале обрабатывался скрипт, а потом уже метод контроллера по примеру как было в Web Forms с onclientclick и click?

Comment: Честно, я и сам не знаю, но в asp тоже можно использовать onclientclick. Можно почитать схожий пример [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860132/execute-client-server-side-code-with-one-click)

Comment: @Nameless есть еще один способ вызвать метод из контроллера после выполнения кода на js -> ajax запрос из js. Но на универсальность и быстродействие данный способ не претендует.

Comment: @ alexoander, а если сделать 2 кнопки одна типа button, а другая скрытая submit и в коде js потом вызывать кнопку submit, чтобы отправить данные контроллеру?

Comment: @Nameless Так тоже можно, но такие ухищрения вовсе не обязательны) можно просто вызвать метод .submit() в JQuery для формы после выполнения функции для button. (точнее в конце функции для button)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле лучше не использовать более одной кнопки с типом `type='submit'` в форме. Попробуйте.